# add gradient background to img tag when hover

Tags: html, jquery, css, hover, gradient

I'm converting the portfolio section on the psd file to html code.
[This is what portfolio section looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQmK4.png)

**I want to add gradient background to image when on hover as you see in the link above.** This is my gradient color.

```
linear-gradient(to right, #f659f8, #de4af8, #c33cf8, #a331f8, #7d2af9);
```

I know we cannot give hover effect to img tag and it is easy to do with background-image property in css. But, since I use [magnific popup plugin](https://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html), I have to use the img tag for images inside the a tag.

I tried to solve the problem to change img tag with div tag and give it background-image, but after this, plugin didn't work.

1. [Here is the default image before hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4t08s.png)
2. **[Here is what we want to achieve after hover on image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1L36h.png)**

The question is: **How to add gradient background to img tag when hover on image?**

---

That is my html code.

```
 <div class="row portfolio-project pt-30">
    <a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4t08s.png" class="portfolio-product col-md-4 ">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4t08s.png" class="w-100 d-block portfolio-image">
    </a>
    <a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4t08s.png" class="portfolio-product  col-md-4">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4t08s.png" class="w-100 d-block portfolio-image">
    </a>
    <a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4t08s.png" class="portfolio-product col-md-4 ">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4t08s.png" class="w-100 d-block portfolio-image">
    </a>
    <a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4t08s.png" class="portfolio-product col-md-4 pt-30">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4t08s.png" class="w-100 d-block portfolio-image">
    </a>
    <a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4t08s.png" class="portfolio-product col-md-4 pt-30">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4t08s.png" class="w-100 d-block portfolio-image">
    </a>
    <a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4t08s.png" class="portfolio-product col-md-4 pt-30">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4t08s.png" class="w-100 d-block portfolio-image">
    </a>
  </div>
```

And this is the magnific popup jquery code.

```
  $('.portfolio-project').magnificPopup({
   delegate: 'a', // child items selector, by clicking on it popup will open
   type: 'image',
   gallery: { enabled: true },
   zoom: {
    enabled: true, // By default it's false, so don't forget to enable it
    duration: 300, // duration of the effect, in milliseconds
    easing: 'ease-in-out', // CSS transition easing function
   }});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### ANSWER

**After many trials and researches, I found the solution of the problem.**

We have to add `<div class="overlay" ></div>` after `<img>` tag and must give parent div to overlay class and img tag. That is the trick. Thus, when we hover the img tag, it will not give hover to anchor tag.

HTML code is just like this.

```
    <a href="img/image.jpg" class="portfolio-product col-md-4">
      <div class="img-content">
        <img src="img/image.jpg" class="w-100 d-block portfolio-image">
        <div class="portfolio-overlay"></div>
      </div>
    </a>
```

Overlay class contains background-gradient and must give `position: absolute`. Relative div will be parent div. And must give `opacity: 0` to disappear the gradient background. After hover on parent divç give opacity higher than 0 to appear it.

Here is SCSS code.

```
.img-content {
  position: relative;

  .portfolio-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: $gradient;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}

&:hover {
  .portfolio-overlay {
    opacity: .8;
  }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The image would overlay the background gradient, so even if you get it to appear when on hover, when content is loaded it would be covered up.

May I recommend you use a `:before` on the anchor tags to achieve this effect.

Ensure that your anchor tags are `position:relative` and then set the pseudo element to be `position: absolute` along with top, left, width and height values.

You can then "reveal" the gradient applied to the pseudo element when a user hovers over the particular anchor.

Comment: I have tried that and other solutions like this but every time it gave hover effect to anchor tag. And a tag has padding because of `col-md-4`. Thus, gradient color width getting larger than image size. I need padding b/w images as well, therefore I cannot remove padding.

Comment: I have tried to give parent overlay class to img tag. But, even though I give img tag z-index: -1;, background gradient doesn't appear. 

`<div class="portfolio-overlay"> 

     <img src="img/image.jpg" class="w-100 d-block portfolio-image img-overlay"> 

</div>`